# Iterating lists and updating dictionary for corresponding match logic improvement

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have two lists:

1. **Users** - [`<UserObject1>`, `<UserObject2>`, ...]
2. **Contributions** - [`<ContributionObject1>`, `<ContributionObject2>`, ...]

Every `ContributionObject` further can have single or multiple `UserObject` in it which are mentioned as `person_links` here and both the objects that are `ContributionObject` and `UserObject` has certain methods and attributes.

`UserObject` has an attribute `affiliation`.

I have to check whether `UserObject` from **Users** and have the same `affiliation` to one of the `UserObject` from `ContributionObject` from **Contributions**.

If yes, I have to make a dictionary where `key` will be the `user` from **Users** and `value` will be an array of ceratin `ContributionObject` attributes that is `title` and `url`.

I am able to do it with the following logic.

I wanted to ask if this logic can be improved further?

If there is another efficient way to do this task, do mention that. Thanks for all the help. :)

```py
conflicts = dict()
for user in users:
    if user.affiliation:
        for contribution in contributions:
            if not conflicts.get(user):
                conflicts[user] = [
                    (
                        contribution.title,
                        contribution.url,
                    )
                    for person in contribution.person_links
                    if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
                ]
            else:
                conflicts[user] += [
                    (
                        contribution.title,
                        contribution.url,
                    )
                    for person in contribution.person_links
                    if user.affiliation in person.affiliation
                ]
```

I tried to find out better ways to update dict values on SO but they were mostly about updating the existing values(overriding) not about adding(appending) to an existing value.

Comment: You can replace `conflicts` with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) of `list` so you don't have two separate cases.

Comment: In any case, if you are comfortable with generators/comprehensions, you can do something like `conflicts = {user: [(contr.title, contr.url) for contr in contributions if any(user.affiliation == person.affiliation for person in contrib.person_links)] for user in users}` (it's not exactly the same, I changed it so you don't get potential duplicate entries in the lists of conflicts and replaced `user.affiliation in person.affiliation` with `user.affiliation == person.affiliation`, which seemed like a mistake?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid going through the contribution list for every user by first creating an affiliation index with the information you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict
affiliationIndex = defaultdict(list)
for contrib in contributions:
    for person in contrib.person_links:
        affiliationIndex[person.affiliation].append((contrib.title,contrib.url))
conflicts = { u:affiliationIndex[u.affiliation] for u in users if u.affiliation}
```

This uses a dictionary to store the list contribution info for each affiliation.  Once that is done, you will get direct access to the contribution information from each user's affiliation.

The resulting performance will be O(U+C) instead of O(UxC).

[EDIT] complexity ...

The big "O" notation denotes the processing pattern of a program by stating the type of curve it would produce on a time or space measurement as the input grows larger.   Linear complexity , O(n), will have a first degree pattern where the time is a multiple of the input size.  As the input size (n) grows larger the time or space used by the program will grow by a factor of (n).   If you are preforming an operation for each input elements that also has an O(n) complexity then yo will get an O(n^2) complexity. For example, building a multiplication table for numbers 1 through n will have an O(n^2) complexity because, for each number you will be performing n multiplications.  So if n = 10, you do 100 multiplications , if n = 15 you will perform 225, if n = 25 --> 625, and so on.

In your original pseudo code you are traversing the contributions list for each user in the users list.  So, if you have U users with affiliations and C contributions, the code inside the contributions loop will be called UxC times (hence the O(UxC) complexity).

On the other hand, if you use a dictionary to build an affiliation index, you will be performing a single pass through the contributions: O(C) and then a single pass through the users O(U).  This will simply add the two processes instead of multiplying one by the other, so O(U+C).

For example, if you have 100 users and 250 contributions, the code block in your inner loop will be called 25,000 times.   With the dictionary you will loop once on the 100 users and once on the 250 contributions, so 350 executions of code blocks.  The advantage of using a dictionary is that it allows accessing data directly without looping (i.e. in O(1) time)

Note that I'm intentionally ignoring the average number of person per contribution because both approaches will incur the cost of looping through person_links.   Technically this makes the solutions O(UxCxP) and O(CxP+U) respectively (where P is the average number of entries in person_links.

Comment: Can you please explain about the complexity more?

Answer (score 0):

After a few comments, I have improved the logic a bit.

Here's the improved logic:

```py
conflicts = defaultdict(list)
for user in users:
    if not user.affiliation:
        continue
    for contribution in self.contributions:
        conflicts[user].extend(
            (
                contribution.title,
                contribution.url
            )
            for person in contribution.person_links
            if user.affiliation in person.affiliation)
return conflicts
```